# Alternative to findIndex for navigating and editing multi-layered object-arrays

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have an object that looks something like this:

```
{
userId: 111,
notes: [
    {
      name: 'Collection1',
      categories: [
        {
          name: 'Category1',
          notes: [
            {data: 'This is the first note', id: '1238123-12931'}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In Mongoose, I need to push/delete/edit notes. For push, I need to navigate to the notes in the object that I want by using a collection name and a category name. For edit or delete, I need those plus a note id. I then need to mutate the original object from mongoose with push/splice/reassign to accomplish my tasks. The way I've done it so far is like this:

```
var collectionIndex = obj.notes.findIndex(collection => collection.name === query.collection)
if (collectionIndex === -1) return console.log('Collection not found')
var categoryIndex = obj.notes.[collectionIndex].categories.findIndex(category => category.name === query.category)
if (categoryIndex === -1) return console.log('Category not found')

obj.notes[collectionIndex].categories[categoryIndex].notes.push(newNote)
```

This method seems very verbose and long to do this and I'm wondering if there is a better way to accomplish the same result with less code.

Answer (score 0):

A little shorter:

```
var collection = obj.notes.find(x => x.name == query.collection && x.categories.some(y => y.name == query.category));
!!collection && collection.categories.find(x => x.name == query.category).notes.push(newNote);
```

Comment: This is shorter, but it still feels like the same structure and feels bad. Is there any better solution to this kind of problem? Should I structure my notes differently to better filter them? What would happen if instead of nested objects, I had one array of objects that each were a note and had the category, collection and id property? Then I could filter a single layer. Will this decrease performance?